# Guice: How can I bind annotated singletons of the same class to different instances?

Tags: singleton, guice

I would like to bind a unique singleton instance for each annotation as shown below, such that `Client1.a != Client1.b` and `Client1.a == Client2.a`.

```
class X {}

@Singleton class OneOfEachAnnotation { 
   @Inject OneOfEachAnnotation(X x) { }
}

class Client1 {
   @Inject Client(@A OneOfEachAnnotation a, @B OneOfEachAnnotation b) {}
}

class Client2 {
   @Inject Client(@A OneOfEachAnnotation a, @B OneOfEachAnnotation b) {}
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221920/getting-multiple-guice-singletons-of-the-same-type/1407719#1407719) seems to claim that I can accomplish the binding like this, but when I do so, `Client1.a == Client1.b`.

```
bind(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).annotatedWith(A.class).to(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).annotatedWith(B.class).to(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Sam Berlin at Google Groups Guice forum. The reason this doesn't work is because the OneOfEachAnnotation is already annotated with @Singleton.  Removing the @Singleton annotation fixes the problem.

Sam explained why:

The statements:

```
bind(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).annotatedWith(A.class).
 to(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).annotatedWith(B.class).
 to(OneOfEachAnnotation.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

are saying, "Create a binding from `@A OneOfEachAnnotation` to `OneOfEachAnnotation` and make the `@A OneOfEachAnnotation` a singleton."  Same thing with `@B`.

Ignoring the `@Singleton` on `OneOfEachAnnotation` for a second (assuming it didn't exist), then this would have the behavior of:

- User injects `OneOfEachAnnotation` (unannotated) multiple times: a new one is created each time, because that binding is unscoped.
- User injects `@A OneOfEachAnnotation`, the first time it links down to the unannotated `OneOfEach`, sees it needs to be constructed, and constructs it.  The second time the binding is already provisioned, so `Scopes.SINGLETON` doesn't go to the linked binding again.
  (Same thing with `@B` as `@A`.)

When `OneOfEachAnnotation` has `@Singleton` on it, then Guice thinks that the unscoped value is *also* a singleton.  So when `@A` links to the unannotated, it will create the first instance.  When `@B` links down the unannotated, Guice notices that the unannotated version, also a Singleton, has already been constructed, and returns that instance.