# Using the provider from two different scopes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following problem with Guice: a singleton service, is injected with provider of context-sensitive information. Until now, context was related only to servlet requests, so I used a @RequestScoped provider, and I was injecting this provider in service like so:

```
@RequestScoped
public class ContextProvider<IContext> implements Provider<IContext> {
  @Override
  public IContext get() { ... } // returns context        
}

@Singleton
public class ServiceImpl implements IService {

  @Inject
  private Provider<IContext> contextProvider;

}
```

That works fine. Now, I'm working on adding background task processing to the application. Background tasks are not initiated from web-requests, so I can not use ServletScopes.scopeRequest(..). I have written a custom scope (almost exact copy of BatchScoped from Giuce doc) to make each Task run in it's own scope. Now the question is - how to make BatchScoped ContextProvider and configure Guice to use it?

I've made this attempt with binding EDSL:

```
line 1 : bind(IContext.class).toProvider(ContextProvider.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
line 2 : bind(IContext.class).toProvider(BatchContextProvider.class).in(BatchScoped.class);
```

but Guice tells me at line 2 that 'A binding to IContext was already configured at line 1'.

The question is: what's the right way of doing such injection with Guice?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `ServletScopes.scopeRequest()`, that's exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: I can not use it, becouse background task is not initiated from web request. So no RequestScope is avialible.

Comment: Did you try it?  I think you'll find that's what `scopeRequest()` does: it makes a "fake" request scope.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question: [Getting multiple guice singletons of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221920/getting-multiple-guice-singletons-of-the-same-type)

In general the problem here is that you want to bind the same class to two different providers (and scopes, but that's actually beside the point).  That is only possible if you use unique binding annotations for each one, like so:

```
bind(IContext.class)
    .annotatedWith(MyAnnotation1.class)
    .toProvider(ContextProvider.class)
    .in(RequestScoped.class);
bind(IContext.class)
    .annotatedWith(MyAnnotation2.class)
    .toProvider(BatchContextProvider.class)
    .in(BatchScoped.class);
```

And change injection sites to include relevant annotation:

```
@Inject
@MyAnnotationX
private Provider<IContext> contextProvider;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you please, explain one thing - my service is a singleton, thus, have only one injection site. Should I somehow inject two providers, and use a non-null one? Or design some kind of delegate, witch does it (probably with direct use of injector?)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  I think Tavian's commments sound reasonable for your requirements, try it out.  If that doesn't work, assuming you had some other scope aware injectable state variable, you could make your provider switch based on that by injecting it as a provider parameter, but that sounds pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a *fake* request that starts with your background task and remains for all of it. That is what `ServletScopes.scopeRequest` does.

```
public class MyBackgroundTask extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RequestScoper scope = ServletScopes.scopeRequest(Collections.emptyMap());
        try ( RequestScoper.CloseableScope ignored = scope.open() ) {
            doTask();
        }
    }

    private void doTask() {

    }
}
```

Oh, don't forget to use providers so you delay the retrieval of your dependencies. For example, expading the previous example so the background task uses your `IContext`.

```
public class MyBackgroundTask extends Thread {
    private Provider<IContext> contextProvider;

    @Inject
    public MyBackgroundTask(Provider<IContext> contextProvider) {
        this.contextProvider = contextProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        RequestScoper scope = ServletScopes.scopeRequest(Collections.emptyMap());
        try ( RequestScoper.CloseableScope ignored = scope.open() ) {
            doTask();
        }
    }

    private void doTask() {

    }
}
```

If you don't use providers the injection, in this example, will be done from the thread that creates the background task which could be inside another scope.

**BONUS**: You may have noticed the empty map sent as a parameter to the `scopeRequest` method. Check the Guice javadocs. Those are the instances that you want already present in your fake request scope. Depending on your `IContext` you may need it.